# My code stops after my while loop, I've put a line of code after to see if it carries on but it doesn't

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1):
    while True: 
        try:
            GTIN = int(input("Enter A 8 Digit GTIN Code: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("That is invalid,Try again")
            continue
        if (GTIN>= 10000000) and (GTIN<= 99999999):  
            break
        else:
            print("That is invalid,try again")
```

After this there is nothing that appears even if I put a simple print command in

Comment: could you repast your code, then select it and click the brackets symbol `{}` at the top, so it gets formatted properly?

Comment: please format the code and give minimum code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please add the line which you used to check if code propagates or not

Comment: where is the code you wanted to run?

Comment: What is it exactly that you are asking? This code is working fine apart from the weird `for` loop at the top.

Comment: Enter A 8 Digit GTIN Code: 11111111
>>>

Comment: so if I were to print it without the for loop then it wouldn't load at all

Comment: @PriZmAKnighT You are not telling us the whole story here OP... Focus please.

Comment: The section of code, has been used in a previous task of mine but for some reason even if I place a line of code, so carrying it on with the rest, nothing is displayed or nothing else appears and it seems that the program ends

Answer (score -5):

If you have provided sample scenario on the line "While true" which ultimately is of no use as commented by many, only the indent is improvement i see.

```
for i in range(1):
    while True: 
        try:
            GTIN = int(input("Enter A 8 Digit GTIN Code: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("That is invalid,Try again")
            continue
        if (GTIN>= 10000000) and (GTIN<= 99999999):  
            break
    else:
        print("That is invalid,try again")
```

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: @Nurzhan not everyone gets sarcasm :) - this is no answer

Comment: does the part in else will ever be executed in the life time

Comment: This may be a part of his code.i could not think of any answer except this indentation.

Comment: @AmeyYadav, the else clause runs if the while condition turns falsy, so, no, `while True .. else` doesn't make sense

Comment: @Recursive, did you run it? you removed the friendly note when the user enters a number too small or too large.

Comment: @ilkkachu exactly while True..else has no meaning here

Comment: @AmeyYadav, sorry, I thought that was a question :)

Comment: @ilkkachu ,Yes. i think the op has just added the first two lines to mimic some scenario and got it wrong.